# Why are my dynamically added user controls showing having their ascx controls as null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I created a new Control `TestControl`.  On the front-end I gave it

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" />
```

On the backend:

```
public partial class TestControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text = "blah";
    }
}
```

When I load the control via:

```
        var control1 = LoadControl(typeof(TestControl), null);
        Controls.Add(control1);
```

I get an exception that `lblTest` is null.

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the relative path overload of the LoadControl method instead, as noted here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtd66a0.aspx

Edit: changed answer after research.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with this control on the loading page, only the code-behind on that page.  Shouldn't that be irrelevant then?

Comment: It still needs to be registered

Comment: I added <%@ Register Src="Controls/TestControl.ascx" TagPrefix="test" TagName="test" %> to my main ascx but it's still giving the same error

Comment: try this: var control1 = LoadControl("~/Controls/TestControl.ascx");

Comment: Yep I just figured that out, that fixed it